# UISplitViewController presenting detail view modally

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm working on an application which I want to work pretty similarly to the messages or Facebook messenger app. On the iPad I would like a split view to appear. On the left I have a series of tabs inside a UITabViewController which allow the user to switch between different types of conversation, and a UICollectionView which contains some information about the conversations. The user selects the conversation and the details view will change to show the actual conversation there.

On the iPhone, i'd like the initial view to be the UITabViewController and then tapping on a conversation will take the user to the details view where they can then click on the back button to move back to the UITabViewController.

Up until this point, I've been testing without the split view. So, the UICollectionView was only doing a push segue to the detail view and this appears to have worked fine. I then last night added a UISplitViewController into the mix and everything has gone wrong. It now works on the iPad, however when the user clicks on conversation to see the conversation view this appears modally and the user cannot exit from this view without closing the application.

My storyboard is like this:

UISplitViewController

- Master: UITabViewController (custom class)

  - Tab 1: UINavigationController (custom class) -> UICollectionViewController (custom class)
  - Tab 2: UINavigationController (custom class) -> UICollectionViewController (custom class)
  - Tab 3: UINavigationController (custom class) -> UICollectionViewController (custom class)
- Details: UINavigationController (custom class)

  - Details View: UICollectionViewController (custom class)

I've tried putting the showDetails segue in various places (from the tabview controller, each navigation controller and even each individual endpoint collection view controller) but each time the details view appears modally on the iPhone and without a back button.

Does anyone have any hints or tips?